# Interior Brick Wall: normal discolouration or mold

Tags: walls, bedroom, interior

I live in an apartment. Do you think the black stains are normal discoloration or mold? We have to spray bleach/water mix on our bathroom ceiling because the porous concrete ceiling easily grows mold.
[image]

Comment: It might be mold. Not all mold is harmful. Get it tested if you're concerned.

Comment: Looks like mortar sand